# Select links in an element but not in children of that element

Tags: javascript, selector

I have a nav bar in  tags. It's an unordered list and within some list items I have submenus (another unordered list within the list item). I want to select the 'a' tags in the nav element but not in the submenus. I have this so far:

```
document.querySelector('nav').getElementsByTagName('a')
```

but it grabs every single 'a' tag in the nav bar.

How do I select 'a' tags in the nav bar but not its children?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *child combinator* selector `nav > a`. It will only select `a` elements that are direct children of `nav`.

See also: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: you beat me 15 seconds so i'm removing my answer and giving yours +1 instead :)

Comment: Brilliant, should've thought of that, didn't realise that you could use CSS selectors in the code

Comment: Yep, that why it is called `querySelector`. If you just want to get elements by their tag name, you can use the `document.getElementByTagName` method. Not kidding. :)